# plot from excel sheets on the same graph using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a excel file that has several sheets and I want to remove the first row showing the sheets name and then the third row showing the units and plot data on 5 sheets on one graph. The x axis is "D" and y axis "S". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXY5m.png)

I tried the following code but getting an error as:

```
x = list(df['D'])
         ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'D'


import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wb = xl.load_workbook('Mohsen.xlsx')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for sheets in wb.worksheets:
     df = pd.read_excel('Mohsen.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=1, skiprows=lambda x: x in [2],
                   names=["D", "S"])
     x = list(df['D'])
     y = list(df["S"])
    ax.lines(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I do not know if possible to plot from several sheets on the only one graph.

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) returns a dictionary of sheets if `sheet_name=None` is provided.

Hence, this task can done by iterating over this dictionary, without adding `openpyxl` into the mix:

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sheet_dict = pd.read_excel(
    "Mohsen.xlsx",
    sheet_name=None,
    header=1,
    skiprows=lambda x: x in [2],
)
for sheet, df in sheet_dict.items():
    plt.plot(df["D"], df["S"], label=sheet)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot Christian!